# Wireshark is giving error message while capturing packets from GNS3?

Tags: wireshark, gns3

I am trying to capture packets with GNS3 using wireshark but wireshark is giving error message every time I run wireshark in GNS3. Path for Wireshark is "D:\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe". Same Path I mentioned in Packet capture analysis command. Screen shot od error message is attacked below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the location of your Wireshark install , make sure it is like
***tail.exe -f -c +0b %c | "D:\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -*** ,for your case.
may you need also to shut down your windows firewall